# Resize navigation icon in toolbar

Tags: android, toolbar

When setting up navigation icon in toolbar it appears stretched in width as an original image. How do i make it look small and nice?

[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ytTA.jpg)

Comment: You can use Image Button instead of ImageView

Answer (score 1):

You should make toolbar icons for mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi, xxxhdpi different sizes. You can reference this:

- 16 × 16 area in 32 × 32 (mdpi)
- 24 × 24 area in 48 × 48 (hdpi)
- 32 × 32 area in 64 × 64 (xhdpi)
- 48 × 48 area in 96 × 96 (xxhdpi)
- 64 × 64 area in 128 × 128 (xxxhdpi)

[image]

For more information, you should take a look at [Material design guidelines](https://material.io/guidelines/layout/structure.html#structure-app-bar)

Answer (score 0):

Oleksandr, **you don't need put menu icon yourself**. Just use Toolbar with AppBarLayout. [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/index.html) explains fully this.

Android Studio latest version can create menu navigation activity template, which you can just fill menu items and actions. That methos step-by-step explained in [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ju837bQOBfg)

Answer (score 0):

Use icons from https://material.io/icons/ . Download PNGs in 24dp. It will suite in toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [link](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/) to get any type of icons in all sizes.